# Formatting Short Text as Numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a column called Amount, with a lot of numbers looking like this:

67000.00000000000000000000

Some of the columns have 2 numbers after the decimal that need to be retained.

Which should amount to $67,000.00

But my problem is, when I format it into currency or numbers, I get MUCH larger numbers than i would like, looking like this:

6.700.000.000.000.000.000.000.000,00

How can I get it into the right format?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: For this scenario, the user was using ACC2013 and the Field Type was Short Text. The method of conversion that succeeded was : `CCur(Val(FieldNameHere))`

---

`CCur(YourFieldName)`

This will convert it to a currency format.

`CLng(YourFieldName)`

This will convert it to a long integer format. (It will cut off the decimals)

If you're looking for a reference, [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) has a few examples and goes into brief detail about some of these conversion functions.

Comment: When i use both CCur and CLng it returns with #Num!

Comment: @SimonTheBrave What data type is your field in the table?

Comment: It is "short text". But I'm not able to change the format without making a query, since I run out of memory when I try to change it in the table.

Comment: @SimonTheBrave try `CDbl(YourField)` - let's see what that gives us. I don't have ACC2013

Comment: This returns with 6,7E+24 for the example

Comment: @SimonTheBrave Will the decimals ever hold any value. or just be 0s?

Comment: Unfortunately they will.. But only in the first two decimals

Comment: @SimonTheBrave Okay, let's try something else. `CCur(Format(YourField,"0.0000"))`

Comment: @SimonTheBrave Try : `CCur(Val(YourField))`

Comment: @SimonTheBrave That's great news. Glad we got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
CCur(Replace("67000.00000000000000000000", ".", Format(0, ".")))
```

You have to replace point symbol to actual decimal separator before conversion. Because you can't know actual seprator, choosen in regional settings, you have to find it  out - and such Format() operation does dirty work.

Comment: I don't see why the `Replace` is necessary?

Comment: If your string contains point symbol as decimal separator, but computer settings state point symbol as thousands separator, then you will get incorrect result.